# How do I import MagickImage

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, imagemagick

I found this example

```
using ImageMagick;

using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage("input.svg"))
{
    image.Scale(new Percentage(60));
    image.Write("output.png");
}
```

and added imageMagick via

```
dotnet add package Magick.NET.Core --version 8.3.3
```

I can't get it to compile, geting the error:

```
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MagickImage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

how do I fix this? What import/using am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a .NET Core 3.1 app, using Visual Studio 2019, I used a specific build `Magick.NET-Q16-AnyCPU` v8.3.3 NuGet package, instead of the more generic `Magick.NET.Core`. Using Q16 I could build without errors. I'm not sure if NuGet is the same thing as running `dotnet add package ...` though.

Comment: Just did a dotnet add package Magick.NET-Q16-AnyCPU --version 8.3.3 and removed the other one, everything works now. Thank you.